# How do I manipulate core data in unit tests while not exposing private functions?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, core-data, xctest

#### Thanks in advance for any help.

I have a caching service I've implemented with a core data stack in Swift 3.1.  The exposed interface conforms to this protocol:

```
protocol WeekForecastCacheService {
  func add(cacheModels: [DayForecastCacheModel])
  func get(cityId: Int, callback: @escaping ([DayForecastCacheModel]?) -> () )
}
```

Ideally I want the internals of my core data stack to stay private.

However I also want to be able to unit test the class.  Specifically the exposed interface.  Because the core data stack is persistent I want to be able to delete every entity (a reset if you will to start tests in a known state).  How do I go about doing this while keeping the unit test implementation outside of my main target.

Ideally I would also like my tests to be independent of implementation...

I'm thinking along the lines of the following but could do with some advice:

- Add a delete all function to the cache class
- Use a class extension and implement the functionality there - it would mean a fair amount of copy paste
- Change private functions / variables to be internal giving enough access to easily create a delete all function in a class extension
- Stop worrying because only protocols are used by classes consuming the service so it doesn't matter if functions and properties within the class are not private

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When unit testing Core Data, a typical approach is to use the in-memory store type to effectively remove the "persistent" part of Core Data. With an in-memory store you get all of Core Data's usual capabilities, but the persistent store isn't written to a file so it always starts off empty. That gets you to a known starting state. If necessary you can pre-load some other known state into the in-memory store before beginning the test.

The key for this is `NSInMemoryStoreType`. If you're setting explicitly adding the persistent store, that would be the `type` value when calling `addPersistentStore(ofType:configurationName:at:options:)`. If you're using `NSPersistentContainer`, you'd include the store type in the `persistentStoreDescriptions` property.